# Custom Metrics in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am publishing my automation execution metrics to cloudWatch. The object which is getting logged is this -

```
@input
structure request {
    executionDetails: ExecutionDetails
    success: Integer
    failed: Integer
    skipped: Integer
    total: Integer
    platform: String
    infra: String
}
structure ExecutionDetails {
    executionId: String
}
```

I see the logs coming in cloudWatch logs, which is good - it helps me in debugging. I am also getting passed , failed, total, skipped metrics - because I am publishing them with the dimension as passed, failed, total, skipped. I want to also see the executionId in the data in the graph - so I can debug from the metrics too. Is that possible ?